# LazyInitializationException with map collection

Tags: java, hibernate

I know that it is a trite question, but I could not find a solution. I have two beans and one of them has `HashMap` collection. I'm getting an exception when trying to read this collection. Mapping config had been specified to load this collection eagerly.

My environment is :

- Hibernate 4.2.0
- mysql-connector-java 5.1.24

Also I have two beans:

```
public class FeaturedDoc {
    private Long id;
    private Map<Feature, Float> features;

    public FeaturedDoc() {
        features = new HashMap<Feature, Float>();
    }
   (getters and setters)
}
```

and

```
public class Feature {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Long internalId;
    (getters and setters)    
}
```

This beans have mapping:

```
<class name="Feature" table="FEATURE">
    <id name="id" type="long" column="ID">
        <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
    <property name="name" length="255" type="string" unique="true" column="NAME" index="INDEX_NAME"/>
    <property name="internalId" type="long" unique="true" not-null="false" column="INTERNAL_ID" index="INDEX_INTID"/>
    <sql-insert>insert into FEATURE (NAME, INTERNAL_ID, ID) values (?, ?, ?) on duplicate key update ID = ID</sql-insert>
</class>

<class name="FeaturedDoc" table="FEATURED_DOC">
    <id name="id" type="long" column="ID">
        <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
    <map  name="features" table="DOC_FEATURE" cascade="all" lazy="false" fetch="join">
        <key column="ID"></key>
        <map-key-many-to-many column="FEATURE_ID" class="Feature"/>
        <element column="value" type="float"/>
    </map>
</class>
```

Also I have DAO layer with method:

```
public FeaturedDoc read(long id) {
    FeaturedDoc fd = null;
    try {
        session.beginTransaction();
        fd = session.get(FeaturedDoc.class, id);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
    } finally {
        close();
    }
    return fd;
}
```

When I'm trying to do something like this:

```
FeaturedDoc fd = daoService.read(26);
System.out.println(fd.getFeatures());
```

I'm getting an exception

> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session

Do you know how should I fix this error?

Comment: Do you know how should I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem! The reason was in `Feature` class. It had not `hashCode` and `equals` functions. After implementation of these functions everything has become ok.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that everything else is okay (in the mappings), have you tried putting `lazy="false"` before `cascade="all"`. I found that this was a problem in my mapping which resulted in this `LazyInitializationException` error.

This ordering is shown in the following Hibernate Reference: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html

Comment: Yes, I've tried, but it doesn't work. Actually I don't think that the order of attributes is the matter.